# Route object validation as props in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the correct way to validate route props in React class?

I tried:

- `route: React.PropTypes.object` - my eslint complains: *Prop type
  `object` is forbidden  react/forbid-prop-types*
- `route: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(React.propTypes)` -  this results in a
  warning at runtime: *Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable Check the render method of bla*

We have the policy to validate props enforced by eslint rules, how can I validate route object?

My code:

```
var bla = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'bla',
    propTypes: {
        route: React.PropTypes.object, 
    })

class RootRoute extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <Router history={hashHistory}>
                    <Route path="/" component={bla}/>
                </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by route props? Isn't it a simple component property? What is the type of your route property?

Comment: route is object from react-router library

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**For you first try**, use `PropTypes.shape`.

Read the eslint docs for more info about the rule:
https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md

Read react-router docs for information about the shape of `route` object: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#proptypes

**For your second try**, inside `instanceOf()`, you need to put a type or a class. I am not sure where you getting this `React.propTypes`. A typo?
Read more about `PropTypes.instanceOf` here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Comment: Using shape instead of proper validator of the Router is more workaround than a proper solution, although it works for me.  Maybe update your answer to suggest to use  `React.PropTypes.shape()`  instead `Proptype.shape`

Comment: @MikhailChibel It was a typo.

Answer (score 9):

You want to ensure that the `route` prop in your component is an `instanceof` `ReactRouter.Route`.

You can use the `PropTypes.instanceOf` function to accomplish this.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'MyComponent',
  propTypes: {
    route: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Route).isRequired
  }
});
```

And the router component just as you had it.

```
var RootRoute = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
         <Route path="/" component={MyComponent}/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
})
```

---

Incidentally, you should try not to mix `class ... extends ...` syntax with the `createClass` syntax for creating new components.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to send a function with returning view as props and changed the instance to Object. `viewInput: PropTypes.instanceOf(Object).isRequired,`

Answer (score 9):

you can also use.

```
PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object()).isRequired
```